# Recuperar o guardar el link antes mandado

Tags: php

Hola mando un link por correo ,asi que tengo la validacion que necesita estar logeado para entrar a ese link , lo que no he logragado es hacer el procedimiento siguiente:
Supongamos que mando el link por correo, el usuario no esta logueado, se loguea y me redirige al link antes enviado... Como se puede hacer eso en php ?

Answer (score 1):

Cuando pongas los inputs para usuario y contraseña, pon en un input invisible el valor de la cadena que enviaste en el link, si el usuario es valido, entonces cargas los datos del link.

Comment: gracias me diste una buena idea